# Trying to install a update in powershell using the KB

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

Like the title says I am trying to install a specific update in PS using just the KB number. I am trying to use Windows Update but I am not having any luck.

Was trying something very simple like this:

`Get-WUInstall -KBArticleID KB4524570`

I am new to powershell so it could be something simple, not sure.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Get-WUInstall cmdlet performs updates based on 2 types of filtering:

1. Pre-search criteria (works on Server side)
2. Post-search criteria (works on Client side, as in your case- filtering based on KBArticleID)

In order to install it, try something like this:

```
Get-WUInstall -KBArticleID KB4524570 -AcceptAll
```

You can also pass the `-Verbose` parameter to get detailed information on what's going on in the background during the execution of this cmdlet. This will help you to pinpoint the issue if something's going wrong in the middle of execution.

```
Get-WUInstall -KBArticleID KB4524570 -AcceptAll -Verbose
```

Comment: Thanks you @Yash Gupta-AIS , I tried that and I got some information back, thanks to -verbose. Would you happen to know what this means:

VERBOSE: BRS-A1045 (5/13/2020 9:39:32 AM): Connecting to Microsoft Update server. Please wait...                        VERBOSE: Found [5] Updates in pre search criteria
VERBOSE: Found [0] Updates in post search criteria

Comment: @RyanSwitzer Glad that it helped! The above Verbose log means that the cmdlet couldn't find any valid Windows Update for the 'KBArticleID' you passed with your post-search criteria request. I'd suggest you to try installing update using any pre-search criteria instead (as I can see your log says that it found some similar updates in pre-search criteria)

Comment: @RyanSwitzer - did the above answer helped you achieve your purpose? If so, please mark the answer as Accepted.

Answer (score -1):

**Get-WindowsUpdate -KBArticleID KB5031354 -AcceptAll** worked for me